# Simultaneous Diagonalization With Non-Similar Eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

So I've been given two diagonal matrices with non matching eigenvectors, 
A:$$ 
\begin{matrix}
    2 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 2 & 0 \\
    -1 & 0 & 1 \\
    \end{matrix}
$$
and B:
$$ 
\begin{matrix}
    1 & 1 & 0 \\
    1 & 1 & 0 \\
    -1 & -1 & 0 \\
    \end{matrix}
$$

Eigenvectors for A: (0, 0, 1), (-1, 0, 1), (0,1,0) 
Eigenvectors for B: (-1,1,0), (0,0,1), (-1,-1,1)
AB=BA (I have proven this), but how do I go about making a joint basis for the two matrices so that I can have a matrix which diagonalizes both A and B?

Edit 1: So, I've figured out two of the three vectors which would make up the matrix I am looking for (that would simultaneously diagonalize A and B). (0,0,1) and (-1,1,1) both belong to the vector space spanned by A and B.  Now I just need the third and I should be good.  I'd be grateful for any input

Answer (score 1):

Note that the eigenspace for $A$ corresponding to $\lambda=1$ is the two-dimensional $\{s(0,0,1)+t(-1,0,1)\colon s,t\in\Bbb R\}$; in particular, there are other eigenvectors besides the ones you listed. Similarly for $B$ and $\lambda=0$: the eigenspace is $\{s(-1,1,0)+t(0,0,1)\colon s,t\in\Bbb R\}$. So you have more possibilities for the eigenvectors from which to form the joint basis.

Comment: So @Greg Martin  I've found two of the vectors (as listed in my edit).  Would (-1,1,0) also be a valid vector lying in the joint vector space?  Adding (-1,0,1) and (0,1,0) of A and subtracting (0,0,1) of A gives me (-1,1,0) I believe, although I am unsure if that is valid since that would not be a linearly independent vector to add...